# Converting wav to m4a on android

Tags: android, wav, m4a

How can I convert audio `.wav` to `.m4a` programmatically using API 14?

MediaCodec and MediaMuxer supported on latest versions API.

Comment: I tried [tqnst/MP4ParserMergeAudioVideo](https://github.com/tqnst/MP4ParserMergeAudioVideo), but its api 18. On 14 api I have not found a solution how to convert pcm data to aac.

Answer (score 0):

FFMPEG is a viable options that seems to be reliable. I'm currently using it in a production app and it does it's purpose.